# Security Restrictions while creating leave request

Tags: python, odoo

[image: Screenshot]

Please find above the Screenshot,

Comment: add access right to this group for `hr.employee`

Comment: kindly guide me from where I can add access right? How to add access right to resolve this errror ? @Anonymous miliana

Comment: open the file `/security/ir.model.acceess.csv`, you will surprise

Comment: .csv file contains the access right group/models, check it

Comment: Look I have given this way but error did not resolve 
__export__.ir_model_access_195,Employee Leave Request,hr_holidays.model_hr_holidays,base.group_user,True,True,True,True,True

Comment: this user `Muhammad kashif` exist in more than one groups

Comment: yes it exists in more than one groups

Comment: He has the following groups
1. Contact Creation
2. Technical Features
3.Employee
4.Pro_forma Invoices
5. Task's Work on Tasks

Comment: in this case try to give to these groups access right to this models `hr.employee`

Comment: Can u write me snippet foe one group. i.e. assigning access rights. Because I'm unable to understand how should i assign rights?

Comment: To get all group of this employee, active debug mode, then in `configuration/group`, filter when user contains `Muhammad Sadjid`

Comment: This shows me all the groups that I already stated in my previous comments.

Comment: Now, try to get the id of each group and add them to CSV file with read = 1

Comment: uhhh. Still  the same Error.

Comment: Yehh. Finally Solved. I had a function for sending Email to Employees' Manger as Employee apply for Leave. And also I had the rule on model hr.employee that state that [('user_id', '=, user.id')] i.e. employee can not see other employees. 
So when I was extracting Manager's Email_ID it raises Access Error because according to rule mentioned above, no employee will be able to access another employee and Manager is also an Amployee.
 So what I had to do , is to extract Manager's Email Address as Super User.

Comment: why you don't post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This Error is raised from the Function which Sends Email to Employee's Manager when Employee apply for Leave. This function searches for Employee's Manager and extract Manager's Email ID to send Leave Email for approval/rejection.

But wait a minute, I had rule in Access Control List on the Group hr.employee which state that [('user_id', '=', user.id)] i.e. Employees can not see other Employees. Due to this access rule, Access Error Warning was being raised.

So I made a little change in  Send Email function, and extracted Manager's Email ID as a Super User. Super user by-passess Access Rights.